# How to test an invalid page locally with rails and capybara

Tags: ruby, rspec, capybara

We have a custom error page.

In production or staging you get the custom error page if you try to visit a non-existing page, e.g.  `/random_fhdjfhdjfhdj.html`

I want to add a feature test to check the content of the custom error page but in development and test modes I get `No route matches [GET] "/random_fhdjfhdjfhdj.html"`

The error page template we use is in `app/views/exceptions/error.html.haml`

Comment: Where/how are the custom error pages being generated?

Comment: ^ I added the page.  Still not sure how it gets generated

Comment: What routes `/random_fhdjfhdjfhdj.html` to your error page? is that conditional on the rails environment?

Comment: One way to implement custom error pages is through seting a custom execptions_app, check your config/environments/production.rb  -  If that's how your project is doing it you'd need to set the same thing in test.rb to test those through the full stack.  If that's not how your error pages are implemented then more info is needed.

Comment: Adding `config.consider_all_requests_local = false` fixed this

Answer (score 0):

Adding `config.consider_all_requests_local = false`
in

```
environments/test.rb
```

fixed this.

---

---

fyi we already had

```
 config.action_dispatch.show_exceptions = true
```

set